# Python memory managment during variable reallocation

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, memory

Let's say I have a function returning a large numpy array:

```
def generate_1GB_array():
    ...
    return array_1GB

array_1GB = generate_1GB_array()
```

and another function for modifying an array:

```
def modify_array(array):
    return array + 1
```

Now let's say I run this script:

```
array_1GB = modify_array(array_1GB)
```

My question is **does this script peak at 1GB or 2GB of memory usage**?

My understanding is that the variable array_1GB now points to a new array object created by the modify_array function. The old array reference count drop to 0, so it's garbage collected. My guess is that the process is not instantaneous, so there is a short period of time when the two arrays leave in memory, so the memory pick usage is actually 2GB.

Actually, in the pandas documentation this example is given:

```
files = pathlib.Path("data/timeseries/").glob("ts*.parquet")
counts = pd.Series(dtype=int)
for path in files:
    df = pd.read_parquet(path)
    counts = counts.add(df["name"].value_counts(), fill_value=0)
counts.astype(int)
```

The documentation says: "*The peak memory usage of this workflow is the single largest chunk, plus a small series storing the unique value counts up to this point*"

Shouldn't it be 2 times the single chunk (assuming there are all equals) + the small series ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: When doing `a = a+1`, a new array is created, and then assigned to the variable `a`.  The previous array is then free for gc.  So, temporarily memory use doubles.  Even `a += 1` buffers the result temparily.

Comment: In your pandas example, the largest chunk will be the `df` from the file just read.  By my understanding temporarily there will be two frames of that size.  But frames don't accumulate in memory.  `counts` is smaller, just a Series, but it too has to create a new Series with each `add`.  `pandas` objects use multiple arrays, depending on dtypes and indices.